# Unable to map \UA using DefaultKeyBinding.dict

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I am using a german Windows keyboard and want to map the key with `<>|` on it to actually really write these symbols. Currently it writes

```
<>| without modifier:        ^
<>| with option key:         „
<>| with command or control: nothing
```

Using the app `Key codes`I figured out that `<>|` has a unicode of 0xA, so I tried these mappings in my `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
"\UA" = ("insertText:", "<");  // forgot what this becomes
"$\UA" = ("insertText:", ">"); // becomes ° instead of <
"~\UA" = ("insertText:", "|"); // becomes „ instead of |
```

I commented right next to it what's the result after of course logging out and logging in again. Other key mappings work fine, I even disabled them during testing to make sure there are no conflicts.

Can anyone help me with this? What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to debug this?

Note: The key I am talking about can be seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout#/media/File:KB_Germany.svg It is the key over the left windows key.

**Update:**
I think I found one part of the issue: I confused unicode code and key code. MacOS expects the unicode code, I gave the key code. The problem I have is that the `Key Codes` app gives no unicode code for the key with `<>|` on it, only a key code (0x**A** -> \U*A* in `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`)

**Update2:**
found the solution, see my answer below.

Comment: What does your topmost leftmost key produce?

Comment: @TomGewecke: Guess you mean the key left from the 1!, right? (topmmost leftmost would be the escape key) This produces without modifier keys: < with shift: > and with option key: ≤ What's your idea behind this question?

Comment: I added an update to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I didn't finish the keyboard wizard for the new keyboard.
Went to settings - keyboard, there it popped up and it asked me exactly for the key right to the left shift key. That's exactly the key causing issues for me. I pressed that key, the wizard recommended me european keyboard layout, I accepted.
Voila, the key now writes < and with shift >. One thing that didnt work was writing the pipe symbol together with the option key.
I added this rule to `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
"~<" = ("insertText:", "|");
```

Logged out and in, and now I can also write the pipe symbol with option key and the `<>|` key.

Lesson learned: unicode code for a key depends on the chosen keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

An easy alternative is to make a custom layout with Ukelele.  See if [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqznryyznt601t3/GermanW.zip?dl=0) does what you need.

Comment: Thank you, didn't yet know that software and the possiblity of a custom layout. Will have a look at it. How about posting your config as code here, so it's independent from Dropbox?

Comment: Found the solution while I actually tried to activate your keyboard layout :-) See my answer below. Thanks for your efforts, without them I wouldn't have stumbled over the missing setting :-)